# How do I play and auto reverse a Lottie animation just once?

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I am currently trying to use the Lottie framework for adding an animation to my app. My code is as follows:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        let starAnimationView = AnimationView()
        // The JSON file
        let starAnimation = Animation.named("qz-checklist-eve")
        starAnimationView.animation = starAnimation
        starAnimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
        starAnimationView.center = self.view.center
        starAnimationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.addSubview(starAnimationView)
        starAnimationView.loopMode = .autoReverse
        starAnimationView.play()
    }
```

This works however the animation continuously loops. I can't seem to find how to set it to a single animation. I have checked the Lottie docs and it says:

`var AnimationView.loopMode: LottieLoopMode { get set }`

> Sets the loop behavior for `play` calls. Defaults to `playOnce` Options: : **playOnce**: Animation is played once then stops. : **loop**: Animation will loop from end to beginning until stopped. : **autoReverse**: Animation will play forward, then backwards and loop until stopped. : **repeat(amount)**: Animation will loop from end to beginning up to amount of times. : **repeatBackwards(amount)**: Animation will play forward, then backwards a amount of times. #

There is **not** a `.repeatBackwards(amount)` option. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it worked for me:

```
    //play animation in full reverse
    animationView.play(fromFrame: lastFrame, toFrame: 1.0, loopMode: .playOnce) { finished in ... }
```

To get the last frame, you need to run it normally and capture it when it is done:

```
    animationView.loopMode = .playOnce

    animationView.play { finished in
            
        if finished {
            
            let lastFrame = animationView.currentFrame    
            print("Last frame is: \(animationView.currentFrame)")

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, if you don't want to take the last frame you can do:

```
animationView.play(fromProgress: 1, toProgress: 0, loopMode: .playOnce) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply Use This:

animationView.reverseAnimationSpeed();

Answer (score 0):

```
private func playForward() {
    self.animationView.play() 
}

private func playReverse() {
    self.animationView.currentProgress = 1
    self.animationView.play(fromProgress: 1, toProgress: 0)
}
```

Try this!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

So that your animation only runs once, all you have to do is remove the line referring to the loop (starAnimationView.loopMode = .autoReverse). 
Your code is perfect, you only have that line left over. I hope I've helped

Comment: it already has starAnimationView.loopMode = .autoReverse. check the code